# Specify path for cookie using jQuery on localhost

Tags: jquery, cookies, localhost, setcookie

I am trying to implement a cookie to apply to all pages of my locally developed site (`http://localhost888/develop`). For some reason, I cannot get it to work by adding 'path /'. Below is the code I am currently using:

Here is the full code being used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var wrap = $('#viewMode'), 
viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' ); 
wrap.children().hide(); 

$('.js-view-mode').on( 'click', 'a',function( e ){ 
e.preventDefault(); 
var t = $(this), 
type = t.attr('href'); 

if( t.parent().hasClass('s') ) return; 

t.parent().addClass('s') 
.siblings().removeClass('s'); 

var lheight = $("#viewMode").height(); 
if(lheight != 0){ 
$("#viewMode").css("height",lheight+"px"); 
} 
wrap.children().fadeOut(); $(type).delay(500).fadeIn(function(){ 
$("#viewMode").css("height","auto"); 
}); 

viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode', type ); 

}); 

if ( viewMode ) { 
$('.js-view-mode a[href='+ viewMode +']').trigger('click'); 
} else { 
$('.js-view-mode li:first a').trigger( 'click' ); 
} 

});
```

I have attempted to add the following to line 3 without success:

```
viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode', {path: '/'} );
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.cookie('the name')` is made for cookie reading. So, `$.cookie('the name', the options)` isn't good.

To create a cookie, with or without options, the syntax is `$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { opt1: foo, opt2: bar, ... });`

Comment: So, how could I transfer this `viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' );` to that successfully? What is `the_value`?

Comment: `viewMode = $.cookie( 'view-mode' );` to get it. `$.cookie( 'view-mode' , type, {path:"\"});` to set it